# validate moves and move pieces on the board in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I have this board [10,10] for this project below and I can't move the piece on the board

this question is part of the other questions about Lisp, you can see on my profile

```
(defun board ()
  "T in position x=0 and y=0"
  '(
    (T 25 54 89 21 8 36 14 41 96) 
    (78 47 56 23 5 NIL 13 12 26 60) 
    (0 27 17 83 34 93 74 52 45 80) 
    (69 9 77 95 55 39 91 73 57 30) 
    (24 15 22 86 1 11 68 79 76 72) 
    (81 48 32 2 64 16 50 37 29 71) 
    (99 51 6 18 53 28 7 63 10 88) 
    (59 42 46 85 90 75 87 43 20 31) 
    (3 61 58 44 65 82 19 4 35 62) 
    (33 70 84 40 66 38 92 67 98 97)
    )
)
```

not the same but similar here the rows begin at 1 but in project is start by 0

[image]

> and this function to print the board

```
(defun print-board (board)
    (format T "~%")
    (mapcar (lambda (x) (format T " ~A ~%" x)) board)
    (format nil ""))
```

> I have 8 movements implemented but I only put 4 examples for the
>   question not to get too much code

```
(defun UP-LEFT (x y board)
  "Function that receives 2 indexes and board, validate movement and move piece up and left"
    (cond
        ((equal (validate-movements (- x 1) (- y 2) board) 0) 
         (move-piece x y -1 -2 board))
        (T nil)))

(defun UP-RIGHT (x y board)
  "receive 2 indexes and board, validate movement and move piece up and right"
    (cond
        ((equal (validate-movements (+ x 1) (- y 2) board) 0) 
         (move-piece x y 1 -2 board))
        (T nil)))

(defun LEFT-DOWN (x y board)
   "Function that receives 2 indexes and board, validate movement and move piece left and down"
    (cond
        ((equal (validate-movements (- x 2) (+ y 1) board) 0)
         (move-piece x y -2 1 board))
        (T nil)))

(defun LEFT-UP (x y board)
   "Function that receives 2 indexes and board, validate movement and move piece left and up"
    (cond
        ((equal (validate-movements (- x 2) (- y 1) board) 0) 
         (move-piece x y -2 -1 board))
        (T nil)))

(defun DOWN-RIGHT (x y board)
   "Function that receives 2 indexes and board, validate movement and move piece down and right"
    (cond
        ((equal (validate-movements (+ x 1) (+ y 2) board) 0)
         (move-piece x y 1 2 board))
        (T nil)))
```

> my doubt is in this move piece in board in axis (x,y)

```
(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
 "Function that receives two indexes and board to move the piece on the board"
  (mapcar 
    (lambda (L) 
        (cond
            ((atom L) L)
            ((and 
             (equal (nth 0 L) x) 
             (equal (nth 1 L) y)) 
             (list (+ (nth 0 L) dx) (+ (nth 1 L) dy) (nth 2 L) 
                   (nth 3 L) (nth 4 L) (nth 5 L) (nth 6 L) 
                   (nth 7 L) (nth 8 L) (nth 9 L)))
    (T L))) board))
```

> and this function to validate movements

```
(defun validate-movements (x y board)   
 "Function that receives two indexes and board to validate movement"
  (cond 
      ((and 
           ;; validation of rows and columns
           (>= x 0) 
           (>= y 0) 
           (<= x 9) 
           (<= y 9) 
           (= (apply '+ (mapcar (lambda (L) 
                                       (cond 
                                           ((atom L) 0)
                                           ((or (not(equal (nth 0 L ) x)) (not (equal (nth 1 L) y))) 0) 
                                           (T 1))) board)) 0)) 0)
    (T nil )))
```

> when I try to test the movements https://ideone.com/jaeCLu it's not move, 
>   because don´t return nothing and show nothing

what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add error message you get? And - what is `i` and `j` in `validate-movements`? Maybe you meant `x` and `y`? I'm just guessing. In any case - that's the source of your problem, `i` and `j` are undefined.

Comment: my mistake but I rename `i` and `j` to `x` and `y` and I will post the error, thanks to see

Comment: OK, now when you changed `i` and `j` - did you test it? Is it working correctly?

Comment: yes, I test `(print-board (LEFT-DOWN 0 0 (board)))` in [ideone](https://ideone.com/tpaIuv) but, I think not move `T` to **left** and **down**, because don´t show the result

Comment: the error is resolved after renaming `i` and `j` but does not show result of piece moving on board

Comment: First thing - your `T` is in top left corned of the board, so you can't move it any further to the left or top. That's the first reason why it's not working now. Define `DOWN-RIGHT` function and test it. Second - can you explain what `validate-movements` should do? It checks if move is not outside of the board, ok, but what should `(= (apply '+ ...` part do?

Comment: it's might be much easier to work with a 2d array.

Comment: I update the question and I put the dow-right and  I test `(print-board (DOWN-RIGHT 0 0 (board)))`  an return error `*** - <=: (33 70 84 40 66 38 92 67 98 97) is not a real number`, you can see the [result here](https://ideone.com/jaeCLu)

Comment: the `validate-movements` receive two indexes to tests if the target location (x, y) is available, ie within the board or with NIL (visited) and should return 
0 => valid move / nil => invalid move

Comment: I try to remove this `(<= x (nth 9 board))`  and `(<= y (nth 9 board))` or put in comment it´s work but stil don´t move

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the validation function.  First, make sensible limebreaks: when a multiline form is closed, break the line.

```
(defun validate-movements (x y board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to validate movement"
  (cond ((and
          ;; validation of rows and columns
          (>= x 0)
          (>= y 0)
          (<= x 9)
          (<= y 9)
          (= (apply '+
                    (mapcar (lambda (L)
                              (cond ((atom L) 0)
                                    ((or (not (equal (nth 0 L ) x))
                                         (not (equal (nth 1 L) y)))
                                     0)
                                    (T 1)))
                            board))
             0))
         0)
        (T nil )))
```

A condition that has only two possible outcomes is better handled through `if`:

```
(defun validate-movements (x y board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to validate movement"
  (if (and
       ;; validation of rows and columns
       (>= x 0)
       (>= y 0)
       (<= x 9)
       (<= y 9)
       (= (apply '+
                 (mapcar (lambda (L)
                           (cond ((atom L) 0)
                                 ((or (not (equal (nth 0 L ) x))
                                      (not (equal (nth 1 L) y)))
                                  0)
                                 (T 1)))
                         board))
          0))
      0
      nil))
```

Comparators like `<=` can take more arguments:

```
(defun validate-movements (x y board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to validate movement"
  (if (and (<= 0 x 9)
           (<= 0 y 9)
           (= (apply '+
                     (mapcar (lambda (L)
                               (cond ((atom L) 0)
                                     ((or (not (equal (nth 0 L) x))
                                          (not (equal (nth 1 L) y)))
                                      0)
                                     (T 1)))
                             board))
              0))
      0
      nil))
```

Since your board is a list of lists (one 10-element sublist per line), a line will never be an atom:

```
(defun validate-movements (x y board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to validate movement"
  (if (and (<= 0 x 9)
           (<= 0 y 9)
           (= (apply '+
                     (mapcar (lambda (L)
                               (cond ((or (not (equal (nth 0 L) x))
                                          (not (equal (nth 1 L) y)))
                                      0)
                                     (T 1)))
                             board))
              0))
      0
      nil))
```

Again, a two-clause conditional is better an `if`:

```
(defun validate-movements (x y board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to validate movement"
  (if (and (<= 0 x 9)
           (<= 0 y 9)
           (= (apply '+
                     (mapcar (lambda (L)
                               (if (or (not (equal (nth 0 L) x))
                                       (not (equal (nth 1 L) y)))
                                   0
                                   1))
                             board))
              0))
      0
      nil))
```

Now, I wanted to tell you how booleans are much easier to express logic with.  However, that condition makes no sense to me: you seem to check that there is some line on the board that carries the x coordinate in its first field and the y coordinate in the second.

Maybe you wanted to check that the target coordinate is empty?

```
(defun target-valid-p (x y board)
  (and (<= 0 x 9)
       (<= 0 y 9)
       (null (nth x (nth y board)))))
```

---

Next, the move function.  Again, linebreaks:

```
(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to move the piece on the board"
  (mapcar (lambda (L) 
            (cond
              ((atom L) L)
              ((and (equal (nth 0 L) x) 
                    (equal (nth 1 L) y)) 
               (list (+ (nth 0 L) dx) (+ (nth 1 L) dy) (nth 2 L) 
                     (nth 3 L) (nth 4 L) (nth 5 L) (nth 6 L) 
                     (nth 7 L) (nth 8 L) (nth 9 L)))
              (T L)))
          board))
```

Your lines are never atoms:

```
(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to move the piece on the board"
  (mapcar (lambda (L) 
            (cond
              ((and (equal (nth 0 L) x) 
                    (equal (nth 1 L) y)) 
               (list (+ (nth 0 L) dx) (+ (nth 1 L) dy) (nth 2 L) 
                     (nth 3 L) (nth 4 L) (nth 5 L) (nth 6 L) 
                     (nth 7 L) (nth 8 L) (nth 9 L)))
              (T L)))
          board))
```

Two-branch conditional is `if`:

```
(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to move the piece on the board"
  (mapcar (lambda (L) 
            (if (and (equal (nth 0 L) x) 
                     (equal (nth 1 L) y)) 
                (list (+ (nth 0 L) dx) (+ (nth 1 L) dy) (nth 2 L) 
                      (nth 3 L) (nth 4 L) (nth 5 L) (nth 6 L) 
                      (nth 7 L) (nth 8 L) (nth 9 L))
                L))
          board))
```

Use `list*` and `nthcdr` to update part of a list:

```
(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
  "Function that receives two indexes and board to move the piece on the board"
  (mapcar (lambda (L) 
            (if (and (equal (nth 0 L) x) 
                     (equal (nth 1 L) y)) 
                (list* (+ (nth 0 L) dx)
                       (+ (nth 1 L) dy)
                       (nthcdr 2 L))
                L))
          board))
```

Now it seems that you again just update the first two cells of the line.  Maybe I didn't understand your data model, but I would have thought that you just want to update the cells at the given coordinates:

```
(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
  (let ((new-board (copy-tree board))
        (new-x (+ x dx))
        (new-y (+ y dy))
        (piece (nth x (nth y board))))
    (setf (nth x (nth y new-board)) nil
          (nth new-x (nth new-y new-board)) piece)
    new-board))
```